# Why does the function work with float properly but doesn't work with double?

Tags: c, floating-point, double, bit-manipulation

I found the code that checks whether a float is a power of 2:

```
int isPowOf2(float number) {
    union {
        float   floatRepresent;
        int     intRepresent;
    } bitset;

    bitset.floatRepresent = number;

    if((bitset.intRepresent & ((1 << 23)-1)) != 0)
        return ((bitset.intRepresent & (bitset.intRepresent-1)) == 0); // denormalized number
    int power = bitset.intRepresent >> 23;
    return power > 0 && power < 255;
}

// ...

printf("[%f -> %d] ",2.0,isPowOf2(2.0f)); // [2.000000 -> 1] 
printf("[%f -> %d] ",4.0,isPowOf2(4.0f)); // [4.000000 -> 1]
printf("[%f -> %d] ",0.25,isPowOf2(0.25f)); // [0.250000 -> 1]
printf("[%f -> %d]\n ",11.0,isPowOf2(11.0f)); // [11.000000 -> 0]
```

It works without issues as you can see in comments. But when I try to turn this program into the version for double numbers, it gives wrong results:

```
int isPowOf2(double number) {
    union {
        double      floatRepresent;
        long long   intRepresent;
    } bitset;

    bitset.floatRepresent = number;

    if((bitset.intRepresent & ((1 << 53)-1)) != 0)
        return ((bitset.intRepresent & (bitset.intRepresent-1)) == 0); // denormalized number
    int power = bitset.intRepresent >> 53;
    return power > 0 && power < 2047;
}

// ...

printf("[%f -> %d] ",2.0,isPowOf2(2.0)); // [2.000000 -> 1] 
printf("[%f -> %d] ",4.0,isPowOf2(4.0)); // [4.000000 -> 0]
printf("[%f -> %d] ",0.25,isPowOf2(0.25)); // [0.250000 -> 0]
printf("[%f -> %d]\n ",11.0,isPowOf2(11.0)); // [11.000000 -> 0]
```

Could you please explain what's the problem?

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but you should almost always use `unsigned` when doing bit operations.

Comment: If your compiler has `sizeof(int)==4`, then `1<<53` isn't defined. Try `1ull << 53`.

Comment: this is implementation defined you need to provide what is your compiler what is your operating system and what is your processor at least.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `0.25` is `2^-2`.

Comment: @Stargateur, Linux Mint 18.2, gcc, Intel Core i5 4200u

Comment: @ntrsBIG Shouldn't that be `52`, not `53`? The code refers to the number of *stored* mantissa bits, with the leading (integer) bit being implicit.

Comment: @njuffa sorry I was testing and preparing my answer before you made that comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for failure is the wrong number of bits in the significand.

In the case of `float` 23 bits are stored of 24.

In the case of `double` 52 bits are stored of 53.

Having corrected that, and added the `LL` qualifier (as mentioned in comments) the offending line becomes

```
if((bitset.intRepresent & ((1LL << 52)-1)) != 0) {
```

and gives the same result as for `float`.

Answer (score 1):

Code is performing an invalid shift.  `1` is an `int`. A `long long` is needed. [@Robᵩ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46916017/why-does-the-function-work-with-float-properly-but-doesnt-work-with-double/46916302#comment80779405_46916017)

```
union {
  double floatRepresent;
  long long intRepresent;
} bitset;

// if((bitset.intRepresent & ((1 << 53)-1)) != 0)
if((bitset.intRepresent & ((1LL << 53)-1)) != 0)
```

Code is using the wrong constant.  An IEEE 754 [binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) `double` has a 52 bit encoded significand. [@njuffa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46916017/why-does-the-function-work-with-float-properly-but-doesnt-work-with-double/46916302#comment80779918_46916017)

```
// if((bitset.intRepresent & ((1 << 53)-1)) != 0)
if((bitset.intRepresent & ((1LL << (53-1))-1)) != 0)
```

---

Code also does not properly work with +infinity.

```
// return power > 0 && power < 2047;
return power > 0 && power < 1023;  // Candidate fix for infinity.
```